# Unwanted homepage refresh with Angular, does not happen with other pages

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I navigate to the home/index page via the "Home" link, the page in SPA-style correctly switches the content initially, but then half-a-second later the page refreshes. This does not happen when I navigate to my "Second" page via the same navbar, only when navigating from my Second page to home.

I'm new to Angular so my apologies if I'm missing something blatantly obvious. I've also included my local server code as I'm wondering if that may be the source of the problem...

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <title>Intro to Angular</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <style>
    html, body, input, select, textarea
    {
      font-size: 1.05em !important;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">jQuery</a>
        </div>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="/index.html"><i></i> Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/second"><i></i> Second</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <div class="container">

    <div ng-view>

    </div>

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**main.html**

```
<h1>This is main.</h1>
<h3>Scope value: {{ name }}</h3>
```

**second.html**

```
<h1>This is second.</h1>
<h3>Scope route value (on second page): {{ num }}</h3>
```

**app.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(function($routeProvider){

  $routeProvider

  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'pages/main.html',
    controller: 'mainController'
  })

  .when('/second/', {
    templateUrl: 'pages/second.html',
    controller: 'secondController'
  })

  .when('/second/:num', {
    templateUrl: 'pages/second.html',
    controller: 'secondController'
  })

});

myApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$log', function($scope, $log) {

  $scope.name = "Main";

}]);


myApp.controller('secondController', ['$scope', '$log', '$routeParams', function($scope, $log, $routeParams) {

  $scope.num =  $routeParams.num || 1;


}]);
```

**server.js**

```
var connect = require('connect');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
connect().use(serveStatic(__dirname)).listen(8080, function(){
    console.log('Server running on 8080...');
});
```

Comment: Your home link is a standard link to /index.html. Have you tried #/ or #/index.html?

Comment: @Marie Holy smokes. I changed from "/" to "/index.html" when trying to debug, but "#/" fixed it. If you'd like to submit that as an answer I'll mark it as solved. Thank you!

Comment: No problem :) I didnt think it merited an answer but Ill go ahead and post it.

Answer (score 1):

Your home link is a standard link to /index.html. Links using angular-route should start with a hash (#) to prevent the browser from navigating away from the page. The solution in this case is to use `#/` instead of `/index.html`